# How Asynchronously process Map of objects coming from Kafka in job which runs in intervals

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, thread-safety, spring-kafka

Example:
Kafka Consumer receiving few records of User object every second.
the incoming User also has "timeInterval" parameter.

```
User: {name: "xyz", age: 23, timeInterval: 30}
```

based on "timeInterval" I need to dynamically run a job which runs continuously for that specified interval. I can have different intervals coming with User objects like 10s, 15s 30s.

**Initial Design:**

datastructure:

```
Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<User>>> intervalUserMapMap;
```

In the job, I need to process the Users grouped by age.
I will add all the users to the map based on the interval and the internal Map based on age.

As there may will be multiple jobs running for different time intervals, I need to run on different threads.

**Problem:**

While the jobs are running, Kafka keeps on pushing many users to the program. HashMaps inside the "intervalUserMapMap" will be updated. This may cause issues are the same Map is being accessed by 2 threads.

I can use `ConcurrentHashMap` but I'm afraid if more keys are hashed to the same bucket that will be locked, then the Map wont be updated since the threads will be running continuously for the lifetime of the application.

**NEED HELP**

1. Is my design correct. If it can be improved any way, please suggest.
2. If the design is okay, then how should I update the Map in this multi threaded model.

**Edit: Code I tried**

```
@Component
public class UsersConsumer {

    private Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, List<User>>> intervalAgeMapMap = new HashMap<>();

    @KafkaListener(groupId = "users", topics = "users", containerFactory = "usersKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenGroupUsers(User user) {
        System.out.println(user);
        HashMap<Integer, List<User>> ageUserMap = null;
        if (intervalAgeMapMap.containsKey(user.getInterval())) {
            ageUserMap = intervalAgeMapMap.get(user.getInterval());
            if (ageUserMap.containsKey(user.getAge())) {
                List<User> userList = ageUserMap.get(user.getAge());
                userList.add(user);
            } else {
                List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
                userList.add(user);
                ageUserMap.put(user.getAge(), userList);
            }
        } else {
            ageUserMap = new HashMap<>();
            List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
            userList.add(user);
            ageUserMap.put(user.getAge(), userList);
            intervalAgeMapMap.put(user.getInterval(), ageUserMap);
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                processUsers(user.getInterval());
            });
        }
    }

    public void processUsers(int interval) {
        while (true) {
            HashMap<Integer, List<User>> ageUserListMap = intervalAgeMapMap.get(interval);
            for (Entry<Integer, List<User>> ageUserListSet : ageUserListMap.entrySet()) {
                List<User> userList = ageUserListSet.getValue();
                // process Users
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(interval);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many jobs for different users, can you run in parallel?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai The jobs also should be initialized dynamically and concurrently based on the interval provided in the request. That means, the number of threads will be equal to number of unique timeIntervals from the incoming requests. 
In one job, set of Users with same time interval will be processed.

Comment: You are saying one job execution will process many users with same interval. Let say `{name: "xyz", age: 23, timeInterval: 30}` is in the topic and pickup by consumer.  After few seconds `{name: "abc", age: 23, timeInterval: 30}` was pickup by consumer. Will the consumer will wait until it collects a certain number of users with same time interval to trigger the job? Will it trigger one first for `xyz` and then it realises there is another message with same time interval for `abc`, and since it has already started a job for `xyz` and will it trigger a new job execution for `abc`?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai The job will be triggered as soon as the first User ("xyz") comes for interval (30). It will not wait for other users to come. If the other user("abc") comes for the same interval (30), then the new user also should be considered by the same job in the next iteration. I have updated some code in the post.

Comment: So your jobs are not unlimited, you have maximum one job for one time interval. if possible time intervals are `15`, `30`, `45`, `60`, you will have maximum 4 jobs running at anytime?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai exactly.

Answer (score 1):

For doing any batch work off Kafka, you shouldn't sleep the consumer thread because it'll rebalance the group regularly, putting strain on the brokers.

So, there's no reason to use Spring Kafka annotations here. You need to manually open and close a consumer on your set schedule

You could also push all jobs constantly into a priority queue if there is no ordering limitations / processing is idempotent

Comment: Here the consumer thread is not set to sleep. I'm starting the job in seperate thread. Thread.sleep is in another thread. Consumer thread is always active.

Comment: @Krishna That's not exactly clear from your question. That's not how `@KafkaListener` operates